# Is there a way to lock down deployments to only be during a specific time of day?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to only deploy anytime between 9:00am and 6:00pm on certain days. I already have the builds locked down by day using "Set approvedDays" but I need one for hours.

Comment: Go to Config --> Build -> Build Periodically and specify the time period

Comment: From what I am reading that schedules builds to happen at a specific time.  I want our builds to be kicked off when a checkin happens and if it passes criteria (time of day being one of them) is automatically does the deploy.  I am attempting to avoid builds going to production when there isn't support around to handle any issues.

Comment: Hi @JasonW. If my or any other answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this Jenkins plugin could solve your problem: https://github.com/jenkinsci/working-hours-plugin

Comment: Thank you this looks like exactly what I was looking for.